# How to write firebase rules with unique ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

this is my problem :

```
WARN: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "id_logement" at /images/-KNx2y3mAkJZ-Poa7R03 to your security rules for better performance
```

I'm not really a master in firebase and rules so it doesn't really mean something to me ... but i know there is an issue !

This is my data structure : 
[image]

And this are my rules !

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "accounts" : {
      ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".indexOn": ["userId", "email", "lat",]
    },
     "geofire" : {
      ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".indexOn": ["g"]
    },
      "logements" : {
      ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".indexOn": ["id_account"]
    }



  }
}
```

I think it's because i don't know how to write this Unique id in rules ! Can you please help me for this ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question what you are looking for to use in your rules is the `$id` notation that is a wildcard to represent a branch key.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ...
    "images": {
        "$imageId1": {
           ".indexOn": "id_logement"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But, keep in mind that you should not be storing your `imagesUrl` inside a two level deep keys. Work your code to have `images/imageUniqueKey/imageData` structure instead of `images/imageUniqueKey1/imageUniqueKey2/imageData`. Then you would have your rules as bellow.

```
"images": {
    ".indexOn": "id_logement"       
}
```

Comment: Thank you @adolfosrs !! For all your advices :)